# Wikidata - request limit for SPARQL queries

Tags: wikidata

Is there a limit for queries on [Wikidata](https://query.wikidata.org/sparql?query=INSERT_QUERY_HERE) (SPARQL queries only, not editing)? I couldn't find any official documentation about this. I wonder how strong queries are limited per minute/hour (and per IP-address).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, there are limits.

Single query is currently limited to 1 minute runtime. Docs are here:
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_query_service/User_Manual

Also, each IP is limited to 5 concurrent requests currently. There's no limit on how many sequential requests can be processed.

These limits may be adjusted depending on capacity and traffic.

Comment: Thanks a lot. What are your sources for your last 2 statements? Are any further readings available? Or are YOU the source :) ?

Comment: I am the maintainer of the service :) You can read those in system configs here https://github.com/wikimedia/puppet/blob/production/modules/wdqs/templates/nginx.erb#L66, but those can be kind of hard to parse for people not knowing all the magic, so believing me is also an option :)

Comment: @StasM I am running queries with at a rate of 5 queries per second (with an interval of 0.2secs), but I still get `Error 429: Rate limit exceeded`. (The 5 queries need not have completed, irrespective of that I fire the next 5 queries the next second.)

Comment: Essentially, does the `limit_conn byaddr 5;` mean 5 concurrent running/alive queries at an instant? Or just 5 concurrent requests at an instant?