# Wikidata Forbidden Access

Tags: wikidata

I was trying to run some wikidata queries with Python requests and multiprocessing (number_workers = 8) and now I'm getting code 403 (Access Forbiden). Are there any restrictions? I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42567516/wikidata-request-limit-for-sparql-queries) that I should limit myself to 5 concurrent queries, but even with one query I don't get any result now through Python. It used to work.

Is this Access Forbiden temporary or am I blacklisted forever? :(

I didn't see any restrictions in their doc, so I was not aware that I'm doing something that will get me banned.

Does anyone know what the situation is?

```
wikidata_url = 'https://query.wikidata.org/sparql'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Chrome/77.0.3865.90'}
r = requests.get(wikidata_url, params={'format': 'json', 'query': query, 'headers': headers})
```

EDIT AFTER FIXES:
It turned out that I was temporarily banned from the server. I have changed my user agent to follow the [recommended template](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) and I waited for my bad to be removed. The problem was that I was ignoring the error 429 that tells me that I have exceeded my allowed limit and I have to retry after some time (some seconds). This leaded to my error 403.

I tried to correct my error caused by inexperience by writing the following code that takes this into account. I added this edit because it may be useful for someone else.

```
def get_delay(date):
    try:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
        timeout = int((date - datetime.datetime.now()).total_seconds())
    except ValueError:
        timeout = int(date)
    return timeout


def make_request(params):
    r = requests.get(wikidata_url, params)
    print(r.status_code)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        if r.json()['results']['bindings']:
            return r.json()
        else:
            return None
    if r.status_code == 500:
        return None
    if r.status_code == 403:
        return None
    if r.status_code == 429:
        timeout = get_delay(r.headers['retry-after'])
        print('Timeout {} m {} s'.format(timeout // 60, timeout % 60))
        time.sleep(timeout)
        make_request(params)
```

Comment: I am new to wikidata and wanted to use it with Python for the first time today.
But I also have this '<Response [403]>' error. So I think it is not related to you nor to multiprocessing. So maybe you should edit the title.

Comment: It turned out that it was related to me. I was temporarily banned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access limits were [tightened up in 2019](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata/2019-July/013283.html) to try and cope with overloading of the query servers. The generic python-request user agent was [blocked](https://lists.wikimedia.org/pipermail/wikidata/2019-July/013247.html) as part of this (I don't know if/when this was reinstated).

Per [the Query Service manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikidata_Query_Service/User_Manual#Query_limits), the current rules seem to be:

- One client (user agent + IP) is allowed 60 seconds of processing time each 60 seconds
- One client is allowed 30 error queries per minute
- Clients who don't comply with [the User-Agent policy](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/User-Agent_policy) may be blocked completely
- Access to the service is limited to 5 parallel queries per IP [this may change]

I would recommend trying again, running single queries with a more detailed user-agent, to see if that works.