# Failing to get image with requests.get

Tags: python-requests, python-imaging-library

My goal is to compute the average brightness of an image displayed at the given url.

```
import requests
from PIL import ImageStat, UnidentifiedImageError
from PIL import Image as ImPIL

def brightness(imgUrl):
    response = requests.get(imgUrl)
    try:
        img = ImPIL.open(response.raw)
        img = img.convert('L')
        stat = ImageStat.Stat(img)
        return stat.mean[0] # Average brightness of pixels in given image
    except UnidentifiedImageError:
        print(imgUrl)
```

The images I am using are paintings hosted on Wikidata/Wikimedia.
Here are some of the URLs that trigger the exception:

```
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/15-10-27-Els%20Quatre%20Gats-RalfR-WMA%202740a.jpg
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Garrote%20vil%2C%20de%20Ram%C3%B3n%20Casas.jpg
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/La%20morfina%20%28Santiago%20Rusi%C3%B1ol%29.jpg
http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Special:FilePath/Ramon%20Casas%20-%20Over%20My%20Dead%20Body%20-%20Google%20Art%20Project.jpg
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Wikimedia returns a 403 error because of limits on queries (I had 100 urls to go through).

Here is an answer with more details on these limits: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61805827/18124080